# Transformar resultado JSON agrupado por ciertos parametros en Javascript

Tags: javascript, array

tengo el siguiente resultado en JSON:

```
const res = {"expedientes": [{"idCirculacion": 47085,"idPlazo": 8062,"legajo": 15614,"etiqueta": 0,"departamento": "Piso3"},"idCirculacion": 47086,"idPlazo": 8062,"legajo": 5614,"etiqueta": 0,"departamento": "Piso1"},{"idCirculacion": 47087,"idPlazo":8062,"legajo": 15614,"etiqueta": 0,"departamento":"Piso2"},{"idCirculacion": 47088,"idPlazo":8062,"legajo": 15614,"etiqueta": 0,"departamento": "Piso5"},{"idCirculacion":47089,"idPlazo": 8062,"legajo": 15614,"etiqueta":0,"departamento": "Piso4"},{"idCirculacion":51567,"idPlazo": 8809,"legajo": 16331,"etiqueta":0,"departamento": "Piso5"},{"idCirculacion":51568,"idPlazo": 8809,"legajo": 16331,"etiqueta": 0,"departamento": "Piso4"},{"idCirculacion": 51569,"idPlazo":8809,"legajo": 16331,"etiqueta": 0,"departamento":"Piso3"},{"idCirculacion":51570,"idPlazo":8809,"legajo":16331,"etiqueta":0,"departamento": "Piso1"},{"idCirculacion":51571,"idPlazo":8809,"legajo":16331,"etiqueta": 0,"departamento": "Piso2"}]}
```

Y necesito agruparlo de esta manera:

```
const agrupado = {"expedientes":[ {"idPlazo": 8062,"legajo": 15614,"etiqueta":0,"votos":[{ "departamento": "Piso3", "idCirculacion":47085 },{"departamento": "Piso2","idCirculacion": 47086 },{"departamento": "Piso1","idCirculacion": 47087},{"departamento":"Piso5","idCirculacion": 47088},{"idCirculacion":47089,"departamento": "Piso4"}]},{"idPlazo":8809,"legajo": 16331,"etiqueta": 0,"votos":[{"departamento":"Piso5","idCirculacion": 51567},{"departamento":"Piso4","idCirculacion": 51568},{"departamento":"Piso3","idCirculacion": 51569},{"departamento":"Piso1","idCirculacion": 51570},{"departamento": "Piso2","idCirculacion": 51571}]}
```

La clave que se utilizaría para agrupar sería idPlazo (Lo que no se repite es el departamento y el campo idCirculacion)

Estuve viendo el método reduce, pero hay algo que no me está saliendo.
La idea es que cuando obtengo una consulta con el tipo de resultado que menciono arriba, lo arreglo de la otra manera para poder imprimir por pantalla. En el ejemplo, el resultado son diez registros, pero lo que tengo que imprimir por pantalla son solamente dos (Y cinco agrupados dentro de cada uno).

```
res.expedientes.reduce(function(acc,e){
//Aca tendría que agrupar, pero no me está saliendo.
return acc;
});
```

Si alguien me puede dar una mano les agradezco.
Saludos!

**Encontré la solución:**

Usando reduce y agrupando por idPlazo:

```
 let resultado = res.expedientes.reduce(function(agrupado, regristo) {
    var valor = regristo["idPlazo"];

    agrupado[valor] = agrupado[valor] || {"idPlazo":regristo.idPlazo,"legajo":regristo.legajo,"votos": new Array};
    agrupado[valor].votos.push({"departamento":regristo.departamento, "idCirculacion": regristo.idCirculacion});

    return agrupado;
}, {});
```

Comment: Los dos objetos literales (no son JSON) son inválidos, eso no ayuda a que te ayudemos

Answer (score 2):

Usando reduce y agrupando por idPlazo:

```
    let resultado = res.expedientes.reduce(function(agrupado, regristo) {
    var valor = regristo["idPlazo"];

    agrupado[valor] = agrupado[valor] || {"idPlazo":regristo.idPlazo,"legajo":regristo.legajo,"votos": new Array};
    agrupado[valor].votos.push({"departamento":regristo.departamento, "idCirculacion": regristo.idCirculacion});

    return agrupado;
}, {});
```

Comment: No olvides puedes aceptar tu propia respuesta, consideta hacerlo cuando te sea posible